# Allowing custom class member values of a user control to be set on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, controls, members

I may have worded the title wrongly here. But what I have is the following user control class:

```
 public class CustomControl : UserControlBase
 {
       public String MyString { get; set; }
 }
```

When I include an instance of this user control on my page, I can quite easily change the value of MyString in the markup like:

```
<XYZ:CustomControl runat="server" MyString="A value" />
```

However, I want to include a property that is of type MyClass, and assign values to the 'child' class:

```
 public class CustomControl : UserControlBase
 {
       public String MyString { get; set; }
       public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
 }

 public class MyClass
 {
       public String AString { get; set; }
 }

<XYZ:CustomControl runat="server" MyString="A value" MyClass.AString="Some value" />
```

Obviously the above won't work, but it gives you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Is `MyClass` a property of `CustomControl`?

Comment: It is now (as per the 2nd code snippet) ye

Comment: Are you wanting to set the values in markup or code?

Comment: "...to be set on a page" (i.e. markup).

Answer (score -1):

In a WPF application I would do something like this:

```
public class CustomControl : UserControlBase
{
       public String MyString { get; set; }
       public String AString { get; set; }

       [Description("Some description"), Category("Data")]
       public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }

}
```

You will be able to access the attribute in the XAML. The issue now is that your class must be able able to be converted from string to MyClass.

Comment: This post explains how to convert to class from a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876683/c-sharp-convert-dynamic-string-to-existing-class

Comment: Would the user who down voted like to explain why? I am here to help if there is anything not working for you.

Comment: I was not the one who down voted but my guess is that it was because the original question is about asp.net and not WPF.

Comment: Same Chris, not sure why there's a downvote on both of our answers. Especially since mine is the solution and no alternative was provided in the comments!?