How can I use a dictionary to swich between classes according to a integer value?
I have a C# application where I have to switch between classes according to the value of an integer variable. I have a string array "myvar" that should get the values from one of the classes (myclass1, myclass2, myclass3....) according to the value of an integer variable (var1). Currently, I am using the following code. I want to shorten my code by using a dictionary. I have once used a dictionary for translating a string variable to a list of strings. But I cannot adapt it to my current use case because here I have to switch between classes. Is it possible to use a dictionary in my case?
myclass1 my_class1 = new myclass1();
myclass2 my_class2 = new myclass2();
myclass3 my_class3 = new myclass3();
//several other classes


int var1 = 0;
string[] myvar= new string[999];


public void my_method()
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 999; j++)
  {
     if (var1==1)
     {
       myvar[j] = my_class1.varlist[j];
     }
     if (var1==2)
     {
       myvar[j] = my_class2.varlist[j];
     }
     if (var1==3)
     {
       myvar[j] = my_class3.varlist[j];
     }
     // same for the rest classes

  }      

}
                            


You probably could use reflection to convert an assembled string to a class, create an instance of that class then (or have the list static if thats an option), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4876683/c-sharp-convert-dynamic-string-to-existing-class But: if you do that, you probably loose some abilities of your IDE (like refactoring usage calls etc), as it no longer knows the concrete type of the variable. Sometimes its a good idea to have a-bit-bloated-but-more-explicit code. Not saying it applies here, you know that better than me.

make common base class/interface which is exposing varlist ... put the stuff into array/list  ... use index ... also, if myclassX looks the same as myclassY than you should prolly use one class ... seems like XY problem

You can create a Dictionary<int, IList<int>> and add those varlist from the classes.

Btw, you have really 999 different classes because you need 999 lists? That should be refactored first. Create one class that has the dictionary instead of 999 different types.

@TimSchmelter  No there are just 999 elements in the variable list. The amount of classes are limited 5-10. Each class has a variable list  of a CNC controller according its CNC version. So for 10 different versions there are 10 variable lists in  10 different classes.

You could define a common interface and have a dictionary based on that.
E.g.
interface IMyClass {
  int GetItem(int index);
}

class MyClass1 : IMyClass {
  public int GetItem(int index) {
    // actual code here...
  }
}

Dictionary<int, IMyClass> myClasses = new {
        { 1, new MyClass1() },     
        { 2, new MyClass2() },     
        { 3, new MyClass3() },     
    };

